# how to search data form XML in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webforms

I'm new to ASP.NET. I am developing a search application in ASP.NET webforms and it will receive from an XMl file. When I type in the textbox like student_name or ID and click submit button it should retrieve the data of the student from the XML like their Honours in a nice format. This is the sample that I have made but it's not working.

aspx file

```
<body style="height: 171px">

<h1>Student Graduation</h1>

<form runat="server">
    Search for 
    <asp:TextBox ID="SearchTextBox" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="SearchButton" Text="Search!" runat="server" OnClick="SearchButton_Click" />
</form>


<div id="student_output" runat="server"></div>
```

aspx.cs

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("student_list.xml"));

        XmlNodeList Students = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("Student");

        String htmlString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < Students.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlNode Student = Students[i];

            htmlString += "<h2>" + Student.SelectSingleNode("Student_Name").InnerText + "</h2>";

            htmlString += "<p>";

            htmlString += Student.SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText + ", ";

            htmlString += Student.SelectSingleNode("Honours").InnerText + ", ";

            htmlString += Student.SelectSingleNode("Programme").InnerText + ", ";

            htmlString += Student.SelectSingleNode("Book_Price").InnerText + ". ";

            htmlString += "</p>";

        }
        student_output.InnerHtml = htmlString;
    }

    protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String searchKey = SearchTextBox.Text;

        XmlNode Student = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Student[Student_Name='" + searchKey + "']");

        if (Student != null)
        {
            string htmlString = "";

            htmlString += "<h2>" + Student.SelectSingleNode("Student_Name").InnerText + "</h2>";

            htmlString += "<p>";

            htmlString += Student.SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText + ", ";

            htmlString += Student.SelectSingleNode("Honours").InnerText + ", ";

            htmlString += Student.SelectSingleNode("Programme").InnerText + ". ";

            htmlString += Student.SelectSingleNode("Book_Price").InnerText + ". ";

            htmlString += "</p>";

            student_output.InnerHtml = htmlString;
        }
    }
}
```

}

XML File

```
<Graduate>

<Student>
    <ID> 01944422</ID>
    <Student_Name>Peter Parker</Student_Name>
    <Honours> First Class </Honours>
    <Book_Price>Yes</Book_Price>
    <Programme>Comp. Science</Programme>
</Student>

<Student>
    <ID>01923455</ID>
    <Student_Name>Bryan Adam</Student_Name>
    <Honours>Second class</Honours>
    <Book_Price>No</Book_Price>
    <Programme>Mathematics</Programme>
</Student>

<Student>
    <ID>01952345</ID>
    <Student_Name>Maggie Fong</Student_Name>
    <Honours>First class</Honours>
    <Book_Price>Yes</Book_Price>
    <Programme>Accounting</Programme>
</Student>

<Student>
    <ID>01998745</ID>
    <Student_Name>Melissa Teh</Student_Name>
    <Honours>First class</Honours>
    <Book_Price>Yes</Book_Price>
    <Programme>Finance</Programme>
</Student>


<Student>
    <ID>01899888</ID>
    <Student_Name>Ahmad bin Suhail</Student_Name>
    <Honours>Second class</Honours>
    <Book_Price>No</Book_Price>
    <Programme>Engineering</Programme>
</Student>

<Student>
    <ID>01900847</ID>
    <Student_Name>Lechumanan a/l Vicky</Student_Name>
    <Honours>Third class</Honours>
    <Book_Price>No</Book_Price>
    <Programme>Comp. Science</Programme>
</Student>

<Student>
    <ID>04503967</ID>
    <Student_Name>Soo Tong Wei</Student_Name>
    <Honours>Third class</Honours>
    <Book_Price>No</Book_Price>
    <Programme>Mathematics</Programme>
</Student>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error? Is it somehow not meeting your needs? How is it deviating from your expectations? Those are critical details you need to include in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert the xml to a dataset, then everything becomes a walk in the park.

So, this markup:

```
    <div>
        <h1>Student Graduation</h1>
            Search for 
            <asp:TextBox ID="SearchTextBox" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="SearchButton" Text="Search!" runat="server" OnClick="SearchButton_Click" 
                CssClass="btn" style="margin-left:15px"       />

        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table" Width="40%">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

Ok, and then this code:

```
   protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sFile  = @"C:\Test7\sData.txt";
        DataSet MyData = new DataSet();
        MyData.ReadXml(sFile);

        // if blank, then show all data
        DataTable MyTable = MyData.Tables[0];
        if (SearchTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            string s = SearchTextBox.Text;
            // user entered somthing
            // if text, then match on stuent name

            if (s.All(char.IsNumber))
            {
                // number, lets filter by ID
                MyTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ID = " + s;
            }
            else
            {
                // search Student name - partial match
                MyTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Student_Name like '%" + s + "%'";
            }
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = MyTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

So, if we enter nothing, then we show all and see this:

[image]

And I used a wild card search for the name - we could I suppose JUST match on say the start, but you can say search for "B", and you get this:

[image]

Of course, if you enter a number, then I search by ID, and say this:

[image]

And I suppose we should add to the GV a "no data row, say like this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table" Width="40%">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <h2>No data found</h2>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
```

So, now for a failed search, we would get this:

[image]